# search value in array webhook

Tags: php, arrays, webhooks

I need to search for a value within a multidimensional array. I have to look for the value 'pa_packetto' which in this example corresponds to the index 0 of the 'meta_data' field and the index 0 of the 'line_items' field.

I tried using foreach but it doesn't find it.

You can see the array json here [array json](http://jsonblob.com/1171080355771179008)

[image]

```
{"id":56,"parent_id":0,"status":"processing","currency":"EUR","version":"8.2.1","prices_include_tax":false,"date_created":"2023-11-06T13:32:44","date_modified":"2023-11-06T13:32:45","discount_total":"0.00","discount_tax":"0.00","shipping_total":"5.00","shipping_tax":"1.10","cart_tax":"17.60","total":"103.70","total_tax":"18.70","customer_id":1,"order_key":"wc_order_IYIY37p1jHN0y","billing":{"first_name":"Luca","last_name":"Rossi","company":"","address_1":"Via Verdi 2","address_2":"","city":"domodossola","state":"VB","postcode":"28845","country":"IT","email":"dimare.gabriele@gmail.com","phone":"345698885"},"shipping":{"first_name":"Luca","last_name":"Rossi","company":"","address_1":"Via Verdi 2","address_2":"","city":"domodossola","state":"VB","postcode":"28845","country":"IT","phone":""},"payment_method":"cod","payment_method_title":"Pagamento alla consegna","transaction_id":"","customer_ip_address":"130.41.239.38","customer_user_agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/117.0.0.0 Safari\/537.36","created_via":"checkout","customer_note":"","date_completed":null,"date_paid":null,"cart_hash":"74f7f2621a2eeffa7e9959f9f8061c9b","number":"56","meta_data":[{"id":88,"key":"is_vat_exempt","value":"no"}],"line_items":[{"id":66,"name":"Mucca Carolina - Crampiolo","product_id":17,"variation_id":20,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"50.00","subtotal_tax":"11.00","total":"50.00","total_tax":"11.00","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"11","subtotal":"11"}],"meta_data":[{"id":565,"key":"pa_pacchetto","value":"crampiolo","display_key":"Pacchetto","display_value":"Crampiolo"},{"id":566,"key":"_WCPA_order_meta_data","value":{"sec_2653f87b87ae5a":{"extra":{"section_id":"sec_2653f87b87ae5a","clStatus":"visible","key":"sec_2653f87b87ae5a","price":0,"form_id":26,"parentKey":false,"form_rules":[]},"fields":[[{"type":"text","name":"text_6623440912","label":"Nome","elementId":"text_6623440912","value":"Fausto","clStatus":"visible","price":false,"form_data":{"name":"text_6623440912","label":"Nome","description":"Nome che verr\u00e0 stampato sulla carta","value":"","active":true,"required":true,"elementId":"text_6623440912","subtype":"text"},"meta_id":588}],[{"type":"email","name":"email_6623338301","label":"Email","elementId":"email_6623338301","value":"fausto.aa@aa.it","clStatus":"visible","price":false,"form_data":{"name":"email_6623338301","label":"Email","description":"Email a cui inviare la carta","value":"","active":true,"required":true,"elementId":"email_6623338301"},"meta_id":589}]]}},"display_key":"_WCPA_order_meta_data","display_value":{"sec_2653f87b87ae5a":{"extra":{"section_id":"sec_2653f87b87ae5a","clStatus":"visible","key":"sec_2653f87b87ae5a","price":0,"form_id":26,"parentKey":false,"form_rules":[]},"fields":[[{"type":"text","name":"text_6623440912","label":"Nome","elementId":"text_6623440912","value":"Fausto","clStatus":"visible","price":false,"form_data":{"name":"text_6623440912","label":"Nome","description":"Nome che verr\u00e0 stampato sulla carta","value":"","active":true,"required":true,"elementId":"text_6623440912","subtype":"text"},"meta_id":588}],[{"type":"email","name":"email_6623338301","label":"Email","elementId":"email_6623338301","value":"fausto.aa@aa.it","clStatus":"visible","price":false,"form_data":{"name":"email_6623338301","label":"Email","description":"Email a cui inviare la carta","value":"","active":true,"required":true,"elementId":"email_6623338301"},"meta_id":589}]]}}},{"id":588,"key":"Nome","value":"Fausto","display_key":"Nome","display_value":"Fausto"},{"id":589,"key":"Email","value":"fausto.aa@aa.it","display_key":"Email","display_value":"fausto.aa@aa.it"}],"sku":"Crampiolo Carolina","price":50,"image":{"id":0,"src":""},"parent_name":"Mucca Carolina"},{"id":67,"name":"bettelmatt","product_id":43,"variation_id":0,"quantity":1,"tax_class":"","subtotal":"30.00","subtotal_tax":"6.60","total":"30.00","total_tax":"6.60","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"6.6","subtotal":"6.6"}],"meta_data":[],"sku":"","price":30,"image":{"id":"","src":""},"parent_name":null}],"tax_lines":[{"id":69,"rate_code":"IMPOSTE-1","rate_id":1,"label":"Imposte","compound":false,"tax_total":"17.60","shipping_tax_total":"1.10","rate_percent":22,"meta_data":[]}],"shipping_lines":[{"id":68,"method_title":"Tariffa unica","method_id":"flat_rate","instance_id":"1","total":"5.00","total_tax":"1.10","taxes":[{"id":1,"total":"1.1","subtotal":""}],"meta_data":[{"id":581,"key":"Prodotti","value":"Mucca Carolina - Crampiolo &times; 1, bettelmatt &times; 1","display_key":"Prodotti","display_value":"Mucca Carolina - Crampiolo &times; 1, bettelmatt &times; 1"}]}],"fee_lines":[],"coupon_lines":[],"refunds":[],"payment_url":"http:\/\/dimaweb.altervista.org\/?page_id=8&order-pay=56&pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_IYIY37p1jHN0y","is_editable":false,"needs_payment":false,"needs_processing":true,"date_created_gmt":"2023-11-06T12:32:44","date_modified_gmt":"2023-11-06T12:32:45","date_completed_gmt":null,"date_paid_gmt":null,"currency_symbol":"\u20ac","_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/dimaweb.altervista.org\/index.php?rest_route=\/wc\/v3\/orders\/56"}],"collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/dimaweb.altervista.org\/index.php?rest_route=\/wc\/v3\/orders"}],"customer":[{"href":"http:\/\/dimaweb.altervista.org\/index.php?rest_route=\/wc\/v3\/customers\/1"}]}}
```

Comment: First convert the JSON String into a PHP Object (or array if you must) and then you can address it quite simply [The Manual for `json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: yes, i decode.. i can see the json array now.. i add the link

Comment: So `$IWant = $data->meta_data[0]->key;`

Comment: no that's not good, because the index is not always 0, but it could change.

Comment: So you will have to `foreach($data->meta_data as $metaData) { }` where I assume there will be multiple keys

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```php
$data = json_decode($string, true);
foreach ($data['line_items'] ?? [] as $lineItemIndex => $lineItem) {
    foreach ($lineItem['meta_data'] ?? [] as $metaDataIndex => $metaDataItem) {
        if (($metaDataItem['key'] ?? '') === 'pa_pacchetto') {
            echo "Woot! lineItemIndex > $lineItemIndex, metaDataIndex > $metaDataIndex";
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add-on:**

A bit of explaining (thanks @KIKO, see the comment):

1. `json_decode($string, true);` - the choice of converting to an object or an array is sometimes a matter of taste, but an array is chosen here to emphasize that there is no guarantee on the composition of its ingredients. Yeah!
2. `$array[$key] ?? []` or `$array[$key] ?? ''` - a small trick. When $array has no key, we just substitute an empty object of acceptable iterate/compare behavior (see null-object pattern).
3. `break 2` - a dirty trick to break both loops at once, if there were three loops, then you would need to write `break 3`. Instead of doing this, you could put this whole logic into a special function and use `return` instead of `break`. Let me show you this and decorating the result with the nice last line, which was kindly provided by KIKO:

```php
function pacchettoCoordinates(array $data): array
{
    foreach ($data['line_items'] ?? [] as $lineItemIndex => $lineItem) {
        foreach ($lineItem['meta_data'] ?? [] as $metaDataIndex => $metaDataItem) {
            if (($metaDataItem['key'] ?? '') === 'pa_pacchetto') {
                return [$lineItemIndex, $metaDataIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    throw new Exception('Vuoi ricevere il pacchetto, ma lo fai senza rispetto');
}


$data = json_decode($string, true);
[$lineItemIndex, $metaDataIndex] = pacchettoCoordinates($data);
echo json_encode($data['line_items'][$lineItemIndex]['meta_data'][$metaDataIndex], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Here are some more tips:

1. don’t be shy to show the code of your attempt to do something, it will be accepted with understanding, but its absence will not.
2. Don't hide the context of the task. Mention of the Stripe system would attract the attention of specialists who could help correctly convert incoming data into suitable objects, as well as help choose the right webhook event.
3. Be careful, the latest version of the code contains enough architectural flaws that require critical thinking.
4. Don't be negative about this add-on, it's just fun)

Comment: Yes, it [seems to work](https://3v4l.org/pp6qi), but your answer requires a bit of explaining. For instance: Why did you go with associative arrays? What are those `??` and `[]` things? and what does `break 2` do? The danger is that dimagabri, and others, will copy your code without actually understanding what it does. Also have a look at the last line of my test code, it would be a nice addition to your answer.

Comment: As you say, @KIKO. Let's make history!

Comment: Wow. I hope dimagabri will appreciate the effort you put into this answer.

Comment: this code partially works (if I'm not mistaken). The webhook in question is from woocommerce. is generated when an order is created. the json array comes only once when creating the order and I have to verify the ordered products. this code works and prints the result only 1 time, of the first cycle. @vodevel

Comment: What do you mean by "only 1 time"? Do you have several items with the 'pa_pacchetto' key and want to handle them all? If yes, then look at my code as a demo version (hint: you can break the limit by removing the break). If you are talking about something else, then a more detailed explanation is needed, please.